# What's the adjective for the spoon when some one uses the spoon, scoops and licks it and then gives the same spoon to other

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's the word when some one uses a spoon to scoop a jam and lick it and then gives the same spoon to you. I would like to know another word apart from "used" or "spoiled" as in my culture there is a specific word for it because it should be differentiated from a new spoon purchase become used spoon after its usage but here it is more impure per se.

Answer (score 3):

"I don't want your second-hand spoon" would fit,  in British English we would be less direct and ask for "a clean spoon please"

There is no specific word in English for spoon-that-has-been-licked-and-is-now-being-passed-to-another;  and we are all the poorer because of it.

Answer (score 1):

**[Unhygienic](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unhygienic)** is probably the adjective you are looking for

> Not clean or sanitary.
>   *‘Well, 99% of this street food is made and served in the most unhygienic and filthy conditions.’*

Alternatively, the following is commonly heard in similar scenarios

> Eww! (or) Gross! That spoon has your ***germs*** all over it

Which is used figuratively and literally.

From Google Books

> “That's your spoon!” Karen cried. “It's been in your mouth and has [your germs](https://books.google.it/books?id=T2zcaOIw1HgC&pg=PT18&lpg=PT18&dq=%22has%20your%20germs%22&source=bl&ots=D140w97TNZ&sig=YMNPAq2J2Hg5md6KqtoDl2czEtQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCpoOMtInYAhWHVxoKHc9UDxcQ6AEIQTAI#v=onepage&q=%22has%20your%20germs%22&f=false) on it.”

And there's also its adjective form

> **[germy](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/germy)**
>   informal
>   Carrying germs; contaminated or infected.
>   ‘buttons of elevators are extremely germy’

Oxford Dictionaries

---

**UPDATE**  18 December 2017

The OP asks in the comments

> How about "defiled"?

If they want the direct translation from their mother tongue into English, it should be said from the beginning. The verb **[defile](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/defile)** has religious and moral overtones, it means to make something unclean (often in the holy sense), and signifies that something that was once pure is now "ruined" or "unfit". Oxford Dictionaries provides this example sentence:

> ‘He was shown tending the pigs, working with a basket and broom, cremating corpses for a fee, and finally breaking down when his wife would not let him touch her for fear of being defiled.’

In the western world, ***dirty cutlery***, or cutlery that has been used by somebody else and not cleaned, has not been "defiled", it is just "dirty". The "dirt" could be someone's saliva or food. A fork that has been dipped into food but not licked clean is "soiled" or "dirty". A knife that has been used to cut raw meat and left unwashed for a day is a health hazard and can be described as being unhygienic. One thing is for certain, that knife will be covered by a multitude of germs.

<sub>P.S The OP should use the  @ character followed by the username if they wish to communicate directly with a user.</sub>

Comment: +1 for defiled...unless it was coming from my dear husband, I would definitely think of the spoon as defiled! :-D

Answer (score 0):

*Contaminated by saliva, 
Invisibly contaminated, 
Booby trapped, 
Salivated upon, 
Slobbered on (or slobbered over), 
Previously sucked, 
Previously used, 
Secretly used, 
Sucked on, 
Grungy, 
Festering*

Answer (score -1):

The spoon was *soiled*.

> **soil** (2) *verb*
>   1 Make dirty.
>   ‘he might soil his expensive suit’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/soil)

Here's an example of this usage in print:

- How do you sanitize it between tastes? // I’ve also seen a container on the counter where the chefs put soiled spoons, which is a better idea; but then I’ve also seen them dip a spoon into the container, and then use it to taste again.
  [- Michael Bauer, A tasting spoon in the pocket; probably not a good idea](http://insidescoopsf.sfgate.com/blog/2012/09/25/a-tasting-spoon-in-the-pocket-probably-not-a-good-idea/)

Comment: "Soiled" is more often used for *visible* dirt; here the action of removing the food by licking has left invisible germs but removed the visible mess.

Comment: A soiled spoon still refers to food that has stuck on a spoon, not someone's saliva, but good try nevertheless :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Oops, thanks for your note. That example was poorly chosen. I’ve updated the example to something better.